# How to perform syncing in android?

Tags: android

I am creating a networking website's Application in android.I want to know how can I perform syncing ie I want to store all user contacts on websites to my android phone.
user's details will come in XML format.

Please Guide me ..

Answer (score 1):

For that you have to make a web service call either by using HttpClient or by using other third-party libraries like kSoap2. But i would prefer native class instead of third-party library.

Here is a best example: http://lukencode.com/2010/04/27/calling-web-services-in-android-using-httpclient/

After making a call, you will receive a XML, after that you can parse the received XML response either by using SAX parser, Pull Parser or DOM Parser.

This is the scenario to fetch data from web to your local database.

For your info: To get response from Web:

```
public static InputStream getInputStreamFromWeb(String url) {
  InputStream content = null;
  try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
    content = response.getEntity().getContent();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.("GET", "Network exception", e);
  }
    return content;
}
```

Comment: OK I have parsed data.The data is contacts information of friends now I want to store this in my phone's contacts information how can I do this.

Comment: It means you want to store inside your contact book, is it so?

Comment: @ AB1209 That is a completely separate question. There is no point asking this in the comments section of this answer to your original question. Also, if you think that this answer resolves your original question then please mark as accepted answer!